Is it possible to make this automation: an icon on my desktop. When I double click it, Terminal is opened and a specific shell command is entered
I would like the following automation. An icon on my desktop. When I double click it, Terminal is opened and a specific shell command is entered.
Is it possible to do that in 14.6, and if so how?

Hence more fully,

The Terminal, or more specifically a new Terminal window if Terminal is already open, would open on the Mac
The new Terminal window should remain open,
the first command "entered" on the new Terminal window would be the command from the automation (eg "cd blah; ssh blah"), ie that should appear to the human user "in" the Terminal;
ideally it should automatically "hit return" so to speak, ie that command would literally run in the new Terminal window
and then indeed the new Terminal window should simply stay open (as a detail, ideally in the foreground), ie the human can then continue to use the Terminal !!

(On top of all that, as a bonus it would be ideal to set the background color of the new Terminal window !)
